# Passing an URL with parameters in Google Charts API

Tags: url, google-visualization

I want to generate a QrCode image with the Google Chart API. The QrCode encloses an URL with multiple parameters

```
http://example.com/page.php?param=nothing&param2=nothing
```

The Google Chart URL to generate this code would be

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=230x230&choe=UTF-8&chld=L&chl=*http://example.com/page.php?param=nothing**&param2**=nothing*
```

But this doesn't work. Obviously, the browser consider param2 to be part of the original URL.

Any hack to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [flex example out](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/08/flex-charts-with-google-charts-and.html). Full call looks like this:

```
https://www.google.com/jsapi/chart?cht=bvs&chs=500x500&chd=t:100,200,300,400,500,600,700&chds=0,700&chl=Savings|Checking|Money Market|Taxable Stocks|Taxable Bonds|IRA|Pension
```

Comment: That URL should be:

``http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=500x500&chd=t:100,200,300,400,500,600,700&chds=0,700&chl=Savings|Checking|Money Market|Taxable Stocks|Taxable Bonds|IRA|Pension``

    http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=500x500&chd=t:100,200,300,400,500,600,700&chds=0,700&chl=Savings|Checking|Money Market|Taxable Stocks|Taxable Bonds|IRA|Pension